# LG P710 Optimus L7 II keep turning off the WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, 4.2-jelly-bean, lg-optimus-l7-2

I just bought my first Android phone, a LG P710 Optimus L7 II. I love it.

Just one problem. For some reason, when i haven't used the phone for a little while, the WiFi disconnects. In Settings> WiFi> Advanced the 'Keep WiFi on during sleep' is set to 'Always'. So i don't understand why it turns itself off.

Any help would be fantastic

Thanks